# Java Script substring through array of string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Have a array of strings in js

```
var arr=["ABC(A),CDE(C),BFE(B)",+
"XYZ(X)","ZVF(Z)","RET(R)",+
"MXE(M)"];
```

Now need to iterate through this and get the last code in brackets and match the value and do some operation on that.

I am trying to substring but getting a error in console like arr[i].substr is not a function as soon as it is reaches the ,+ part in the array.

Code to iterate through the array.

```
for(var i=0,len=arr.length;i<len;i++)
{
     if(arr[i].substr(length-1,length-2)!=L)
     {
         console.log("my code is "+arr[i].substr(length-1,length-2);
     }
}
```

It is failing after reading till "B" saying that arr[i].substr is not a function may be because of ",+" can someone help? tried searching on google but could not get through similar case.

Comment: isn't it a typo here: substr(length-1,length-2!=L). Should be substr(length-1,length-2) !=L i think

Comment: Your array definition is invalid, the `+` before the string will be interpreted as the unary operator which will be causing all kinds of weird behaviour.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan:: yeah , Is there any solution to this? i mean if i keep the + in place and still use it as a normal array.

Comment: A quick check you can do is take your array and remove the +, and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Why are you using the `+`?

Comment: What is `L`?  Its not assigned a value.

Comment: error will go away if i remove the + but I do not want to modify the array just want to reuse it and would like to make change during or just before the iteration.

Comment: You ***have*** to remove the `+` as it's causing the string values to be converted to a Number in its current location. I don't even know what you're expecting it to do?

Comment: the + in front of a string implicitly do a conversion to integer... try `console.log(typeof +"12")`

Comment: Ohkay guys !! Thanks for your response.Was just expecting some magic here.I knew that was problem with that + as it was printing till the first 3 values before + I thought there could be a solution which i don't know.

Comment: `but I do not want to modify the array` - the array you actually have is not the array you think you have because of the **+** ... remove them is the ONLY option

Comment: not sure whats the need of down voting here

Comment: @NeverGiveUp161 its not printing the first 3 values before the first `+`, there is only one array element before the first `+`, its a single string that contains commas.

Comment: Understood,but unfortunately can't modify that code,So created a simple array with just the required code.

Comment: What is "last code in brackets"?  Are you referring to the last element of the array or the last character that is enclosed in parenthesis in the array? Last character enclosed in parenthesis per element in the array?  All the characters that are enclosed in parenthesis?

Comment: @NeverGiveUp161 the downvotes are because your question isn't clear and your code examples leave out several key things - as pointed out in Adam Konieska's answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues here.

First, to clarify, the first element in your array is a single string, after that your getting problems starting at the `+` operator in your array.  The operator is attempting to add the string in the array, but it fails to convert the string to a number so it returns `NaN`.

Your array:

```
var arr=["ABC(A),CDE(C),BFE(B)",+
"XYZ(X)","ZVF(Z)","RET(R)",+
"MXE(M)"];
```

Is actually processed as:

> ["ABC(A),CDE(C),BFE(B)", NaN, "ZVF(Z)", "RET(R)", NaN]

Note that the first element in the array is a single string of  `"ABC(A),CDE(C),BFE(B)"`  Keep in mind that even though it contains commas, its still a single array element.

Secondly, in your if statement `if(arr[i].substr(length-1,length-2)!=L)` the variable `L` is not defined anywhere.  This will throw and error.

Finally, in your string manipulation statement `console.log("my code is "+arr[i].substr(length-1,length-2);` you want to use `substring()` instead of `substr()` since you are moving to a specific position and not by a number of characters.  Further, `length` is not defined.  You need to change this to the array element's length by using `arr[i].length` instead.

Overall with these changes your code would look like:

```
var arr=["ABC(A)","CDE(C)","BFE(B)","XYZ(X)","ZVF(Z)","RET(R)","MXE(M)"];

for(var i=0; i < arr.length;i++) {
  console.log("my code is "+arr[i].substring(arr[i].length-1,arr[i].length-2));
}
```

Which would output:

> my code is A
>   my code is C
>   my code is B
>   my code is X
>   my code is Z
>   my code is R
>   my code is M

You can see it working in this JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3dgdc4sr/1/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, Not exactly the answer but it helped to understand my mistakes

Answer (score -1):

The `+"XYZ"` part are interpreted as a `NaN`, it's a kindof shortend for parseInt() Substring method are not know on a `NaN` ;)

If you don't need that `+` you can erase it. (javascript can be write on multiple lines with no need of that ;)

EDIT: 
That is your final array, interpreted by the browser :

```
["ABC(A),CDE(C),BFE(B)", NaN, "ZVF(Z)", "RET(R)", NaN]
```

Comment: Thanks!! got it, was expecting some magic tricks on stack overflow to work around that,finally created a new array without + with just the codes.